# Surf dependency causes "cannot be shared between threads safely" error in previously compiling program with matrix_sdk and async-trait

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I'm trying to write a chat bot that supports the matrix protocol, and I ran into this problem that I can't wrap my head around. On its own the code compiles without issue, but adding "surf" as a dependency to the Cargo.toml causes a "dyn log::kv::source::Source` cannot be shared between threads safely" error.

This is the minimal code for which this happens:

main.rs:

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use matrix_sdk::{
    Client, Result,
    ruma::{UserId},
};
use async_trait::async_trait;
    
async fn new_matrix_connector() -> Option<()> {
    let username = "NAME";
    let password = "PASSWORD";

    let alice = match UserId::try_from(username) {
        Ok(user) => user,
        Err(_) => {return None;}
    };
    let client = match Client::new_from_user_id(alice.clone()).await {
        Ok(client) => client,
        Err(_) => {return None;}
    };
    match client.login(alice.localpart(), password, None, None).await {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(_) => {return None;}
    }
    Some(())
}
    
#[async_trait]
trait Loader {
    async fn load(&self) -> Option<()>;
}
    
struct TestLoader {}
    
#[async_trait]
impl Loader for TestLoader {
    async fn load(&self) -> Option<()> {
        new_matrix_connector().await
    }
}
    
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let loader = TestLoader{};
    let _res = loader.load();
    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "matrixtest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
        
[dependencies]
matrix-sdk = "0.4.1"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
async-trait = "0.1.52"
surf = "2.3.2"
```

These are the full errors caused:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn log::kv::source::Source` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:38:40
   |
38 |       async fn load(&self) -> Option<()> {
   |  ________________________________________^
39 | |         new_matrix_connector().await
40 | |     }
   | |_____^ `dyn log::kv::source::Source` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn log::kv::source::Source`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&dyn log::kv::source::Source`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `log::KeyValues<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `log::Record<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `log::RecordBuilder<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6, 't7, 't8, 't9, 't10, 't11, 't12, 't13, 't14, 't15, 't16, 't17, 't18, 't19, 't20, 't21, 't22, 't23, 't24, 't25> {ResumeTy, log::Level, log::Metadata<'r>, &'s (dyn log::Log + 't0), &'t1 mut log::RecordBuilder<'t2>, log::RecordBuilder<'t3>, &'t4 str, std::option::Option<&'t5 str>, u32, std::option::Option<u32>, [&'t6 str; 2], &'t7 [&'t8 str], &'t9 [&'t10 str; 2], &'t11 matrix_sdk::Client, impl for<'t12> std::future::Future, (), tracing_core::subscriber::Interest, &'t13 tracing_core::metadata::Metadata<'t14>, tracing_core::field::Iter, &'t15 tracing_core::field::FieldSet, &'t16 mut tracing_core::field::Iter, std::option::Option<tracing_core::field::Field>, tracing_core::field::Field, &'t17 tracing_core::field::Field, LoginInfo<'t18>, matrix_sdk::ruma::api::ruma_client_api::r0::session::login::Request<'t19>, std::option::Option<RequestConfig>, impl for<'t20, 't21> std::future::Future, matrix_sdk::ruma::api::ruma_client_api::r0::session::login::Response, matrix_sdk::Client, &'t22 matrix_sdk_base::client::BaseClient, matrix_sdk_base::client::BaseClient, &'t23 matrix_sdk::ruma::api::ruma_client_api::r0::session::login::Response, impl for<'t24, 't25> std::future::Future}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}::{closure#0}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}::{closure#0}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6, 't7, 't8, 't9, 't10> {ResumeTy, &'r matrix_sdk::Client, &'s str, std::option::Option<&'t0 str>, tracing::span::Span, impl for<'t1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5> std::future::Future, tracing::instrument::Instrumented<impl for<'t6, 't7, 't8, 't9, 't10> std::future::Future>, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6> {ResumeTy, &'r str, matrix_sdk::ruma::UserId, &'s matrix_sdk::ruma::UserId, impl std::future::Future, (), matrix_sdk::Client, &'t0 matrix_sdk::Client, std::option::Option<&'t1 str>, impl for<'t2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6> std::future::Future}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:8:47: 27:2]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:8:47: 27:2]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r> {ResumeTy, &'r TestLoader, impl std::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:38:40: 40:6]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:38:40: 40:6]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::option::Option<()>> + Send`

error[E0277]: `core::fmt::Opaque` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:38:40
   |
38 |       async fn load(&self) -> Option<()> {
   |  ________________________________________^
39 | |         new_matrix_connector().await
40 | |     }
   | |_____^ `core::fmt::Opaque` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `[ArgumentV1<'_>]`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `core::fmt::Opaque`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `&core::fmt::Opaque`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `ArgumentV1<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[ArgumentV1<'_>]`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&[ArgumentV1<'_>]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Arguments<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `log::Record<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `log::RecordBuilder<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6, 't7, 't8, 't9, 't10, 't11, 't12, 't13, 't14, 't15, 't16, 't17, 't18, 't19, 't20, 't21, 't22, 't23, 't24, 't25> {ResumeTy, log::Level, log::Metadata<'r>, &'s (dyn log::Log + 't0), &'t1 mut log::RecordBuilder<'t2>, log::RecordBuilder<'t3>, &'t4 str, std::option::Option<&'t5 str>, u32, std::option::Option<u32>, [&'t6 str; 2], &'t7 [&'t8 str], &'t9 [&'t10 str; 2], &'t11 matrix_sdk::Client, impl for<'t12> std::future::Future, (), tracing_core::subscriber::Interest, &'t13 tracing_core::metadata::Metadata<'t14>, tracing_core::field::Iter, &'t15 tracing_core::field::FieldSet, &'t16 mut tracing_core::field::Iter, std::option::Option<tracing_core::field::Field>, tracing_core::field::Field, &'t17 tracing_core::field::Field, LoginInfo<'t18>, matrix_sdk::ruma::api::ruma_client_api::r0::session::login::Request<'t19>, std::option::Option<RequestConfig>, impl for<'t20, 't21> std::future::Future, matrix_sdk::ruma::api::ruma_client_api::r0::session::login::Response, matrix_sdk::Client, &'t22 matrix_sdk_base::client::BaseClient, matrix_sdk_base::client::BaseClient, &'t23 matrix_sdk::ruma::api::ruma_client_api::r0::session::login::Response, impl for<'t24, 't25> std::future::Future}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}::{closure#0}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}::{closure#0}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6, 't7, 't8, 't9, 't10> {ResumeTy, &'r matrix_sdk::Client, &'s str, std::option::Option<&'t0 str>, tracing::span::Span, impl for<'t1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5> std::future::Future, tracing::instrument::Instrumented<impl for<'t6, 't7, 't8, 't9, 't10> std::future::Future>, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@matrix_sdk::Client::login::{closure#0}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6> {ResumeTy, &'r str, matrix_sdk::ruma::UserId, &'s matrix_sdk::ruma::UserId, impl std::future::Future, (), matrix_sdk::Client, &'t0 matrix_sdk::Client, std::option::Option<&'t1 str>, impl for<'t2, 't3, 't4, 't5, 't6> std::future::Future}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:8:47: 27:2]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:8:47: 27:2]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r> {ResumeTy, &'r TestLoader, impl std::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:38:40: 40:6]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:38:40: 40:6]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = std::option::Option<()>> + Send`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `matrix` due to 2 previous errors
```

Without the surf dependency this compiles without issue. It also doesn't happen if the load() function is implemented for the TestLoader struct directly.

Comment: I would assume the reason is "surf" depends on `log` with the feature "kv_unstable", and causes `Source` to not be `Sync` anymore. Either that or what it's used for does that (per its description, `kv_unstable` is used to "capure structured data"). Also log 0.4.17 specifically advertises " incorrect combination of kv_unstable and std features causing compile failures.", surf depends on 0.4.7. I'd suggest trying to update Surf's version of log and / or discussing this with the surf project (it doesn't look like log is an optional dep so you can't bypass that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine figured out what the problem was:

The problem wasn't *surf* directly, but the *tracing* crate with the *log* feature enabled, on which *surf* indirectly depends. There is already an [issue on github](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/issues/1487) on it, but it's not yet resolved.

The problem gets triggered by *matrix-sdk* because it also uses *tracing*, but usually without the *log* feature. The line that triggers it is this:

```rust
info!("Registering to {}", self.homeserver().await);
```

Changing it to

```
let homeserver = self.homeserver().await;
info!("Registering to {}", homeserver);
```

resolves the issue. A fix to this exists in a fork of *matrix-sdk* (fixed in [this](https://github.com/jplatte/matrix-rust-sdk/commit/3621b62418c07a3cb3c6482ba1c9455afffb2d4f) commit), but as far as I can tell it hasn't been merged as of yet. There was also no release since then (most recent version is 0.4.1), so maybe it'll get fixed for the next release.

For the time being my workaround for this problem is to not depend on *surf*.